# Replacing multiple strings inside a column using Regexp_replace in hive

Tags: sql, string, hive

I've been trying to replace a list of substrings that can be present in a column in Hive:
Examples of such strings: "SA", "DE", "CV", "MI" etc.

I tried to replace them using the `regexp_replace` function in Hive. To test it out I wrote down the following query:

`select regexp_replace(company_name," DE | SA | CV ", " "), company_name from table limit 20;`

I thought it would tackle all cases but then I had the following output for the same:

ALCA SA DE CV ->>>>>>>>> ALCA DE CV

MEXICANA DE LAMINACION SA CV ->>>>>>>> MEXICANA LAMINACION CV

I tried inserting \s* at the start and front of the characters as well but the output was the same. Is there a way to replace them all in one go? Thank you

Comment: you only want to replace these words when they occur in any part of the sentence except the beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have space before and after regex argument. Pls use this

```
regexp_replace("MEXICANA DE SA LAMINACION SA CV "," DE| SA| CV", " ") 

select regexp_replace(company_name," DE| SA| CV", " "), company_name from table limit 20;
```

Pls notice i used 1 space after the argument. And if you have a word that starts with DE or SA or CV will cause problem and we can handle them separately.

Why your code isnt working -
when you replace " SA " by " " from "ALCA SA DE CV" --> this becomes "ALCA DE CV".But pls notice if you consider " SA ", the character DE doesnt have space before the string. This is why DE will not be replaced. And CV doesnt have a space after string so it will not be replaced. So, this means you will get "ALCA DE CV"

Comment: Yes this works for a subset of cases, but there is no restriction on the names. A name can also start with DE or SA as well. So it might end up replacing it from the start of the name as well.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on this, I was able to resolve it myself due to the explanation

Comment: does this resolves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the list of substrings that were occurring in regex, I used the following query below (though this will also remove it if it occurs at the end of words but my use case can handle them being removed from the end of a word)

`regexp_replace(concat(company_name, " "), "ABP\\s|AC\\s|AMBI\\s|AR\\s|CV\\s|DE\\s|EN\\s|ENR\\s|IAP\\s", " ")`